# How to show an AlertDialog in class which extends Application

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a class which extends Application. 
The goal is to show an AlertDialog (with 1 OK button), immediately after the apllication begins and only then (every time the user runs the app, but **not** every time the user enter to the main Activity from other Activities ).

The name of the main Activity is Activity1.

So here is the class  which extends Application:

```
   public class MyApp extends Application {
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            Activity1 myActivity1=new Activity1();

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(myActivity1);
             builder.setMessage("Hello").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK",                                                                   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //do things
               }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    }
```

This is the error I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application…...NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
```

I guess activity1 is not the right argument. I tried the "this" argument also. I mean:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

It also didn't help.

If someone has any idea about this, I'll appreciate the help. Thank you!

Comment: Why not show the dialog inside the onCreate() method of your Main Activity?

Comment: @ Bidhan A Hi, because then I will see this dialog everytime I will enter to this Activity, and I would like to see it only in the begining of the application.

Comment: Sorry to get picky, but you need to define what "the application begins" means.

Is it the first time the MainActivity is created (and not after every orientation)?
What if I press the home button, leave it for some time and then come back? Note that the activity might still be in the backstack, therefor it is simply brought in the foreground.

Comment: Do you want to show this dialog everytime the user runs the app or only when the user runs the app for the first time?

Comment: @user367361 Hi, you are not picky at all and you right. I'm not advanced in Android so for now I mean a regular start when all the rest options you wrote are not important. No orientations, no home button, no leaving it for some time and then come back. Just start the application. The important thing is I don't want to see this dialog every time I enter the Activity.

Comment: @ Bidhan A Hi, the first option: to show this dialog every time the user runs the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a class that extends Application that has a boolean value. This is used to store global values that last as long as the Application is running.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public boolean hasShownAlertDialog = false; // you can do private and use getter/setters, but, that's frowned upon.
}
```

In your android manifest, under application, you need to define that you're using a custom implementation.

```
<application android:name="com.example.MyApplication" [...]>
```

In your Activity1, in onCreate, you check the global variable:

```
public void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    ...
    if (!(MyApplication)getApplication().hasShownAlertDialog) {
        // show alert dialog
        (MyApplication)getApplication().hasShownAlertDialog = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, If Activity1 will be the place where I disply the alert dialog, I will see this dialog every time I enter this Activity. My goal is to see this dialog every time I begin the application and not every time I enter the Activity.

Comment: Ah. Then you do want to extend Application, declare that you're doing so in your android manifest, add a boolean value in that stores whether the app has shown that dialog yet during the current run. I will edit my current answer with code example. :)

Comment: I'll check it and comeback.

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable to determine if you've already shown the dialog or not. Your MyApp would look like this

```
    public class MyApp extends Application {

    // showDialog will be true for the first time
    private boolean showDialog = true;

    public boolean getDialog() {
        return showDialog;
    }

    public void setDialog(boolean showDialog) {
        this.showDialog = showDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();



    }
}
```

Then inside the onCreate() method of your Activity1 add the following

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    boolean showDialog = ((MyApp) this.getApplication()).getDialog();
    if(showDialog == true) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Show dialog", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Hello").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK",                                                                   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //do things
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        // Set showDialog to false now so you don't see it again
        ((MyApp) this.getApplication()).setDialog(false);
    }
    else {
        Log.d("DIALOG", "Do not show dialog");
    }

}
```

Don't forget to declare your Application class inside of your Manifest file. Inside the `<application>` tag add `android:name=".MyApp"`. For example:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:icon=""
    ....
>
```